# Indesign file. Text thrown off while sorting pages

Tags: page-layout

While I am formatting my indesign file, sometimes removing pages or adding them throws neatly formatted text off the margins. Why

Comment: Can you provide more informations please?

Answer (score 3):

1) If you have Left and Right master pages, make sure the margin is the same on both. Not mirrored (6p outside/3p inside), but the same (3p all around).

2) Make sure you don't have text boxes leaking onto the pasteboard; sometimes that makes text boxes fall off when you rearrange things.